# How do I comment something?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

If an answer was added by others how can I comment it?

Comment: This is a meta question.

Answer (score 3):

You need a reputation of at least 50 to comment on other people's answers. You can always comment on your own questions and answers, and on answers to your own questions. This is explained in the [Stack Overflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).