# What's the justification for the commenting reputation requirement?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, new-users

You require a reputation of 50 to leave comments on others' questions/answers; the FAQ simply states this as a fact but does not explain it. I'm a new user and I have identified this as an issue very quickly through my own experiences so far. Looking at other questions seems to also provide justification against this 50 reputation requirement for comments on others' questions/answers.

[How do I comment something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47868/how-to-comment-an-answer-by-myself)

[Answer or comment: what's the etiquette?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)

In my own experience, I've seen a few questions like "how do I do x?" then the same poster has answered with "in the end I did it like this: ..." where their solution was perfectly sensible, but there may be some gotchas to watch for - in this case I want to vote up their answer and/or comment on it to point out the potential gotchas, but I can do neither!

To me all of the above seems justification against this rep requirement to comment, so what is the counter-argument and justification for it?

Comment: I think that might be part of it.

Comment: This seems covered on both [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment) and [Remove reputation minimum to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/remove-reputation-minimum-to-comment).

Comment: see also: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: This is not a dupe. The other question is a feature request asking to lower the threshold, this one here is a discussion about the reason why it's the way it is. **Not the same thing**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The justification is simple: we don't want the site to be flooded by comments from passers-by.

50 rep points is not an extremely high threshold. You can bookmark the question (not necessarily in your browser, just use the "favorite" star), gain some rep, and then return to it later.

Comment: This does make sense, but if random spammers can post questions/answers anyway it seems a bit strange to restrict comments. It also very frustrating for new users and I think it is bound to lead to comments being posted as "answers" which reduces the relevancy.

Comment: I just had to, again, add a comment as an answer (only 41 rep on StackOverflow) and thought I'd stop in here to see if anyone else raised this point. I would vote your comment up if I could. I think the problem is, not everything is an answer to thee question. In my case I've tried to contributed to someone else's answer or ask for clarification on an answer.

Comment: It's easy to see WHY this is in place, but it annoys me. On StackOverflow i have enough points to comment, but not on programmers.SE. So i have two choices, pretend that i know about an answer i have no idea about and hope to get points, or just be quiet. I don't like either :/

Comment: @Bojan: get to just 201 points on any site of the network, then you will get a 100-point rep bonus on every other site — enabling you to upvote, flag, leave comments, and edit community wikis right away. Just go get those 25 points on SO already.

Comment: That might be a problem, going to Australia tomorrow and I'm not taking my laptop with me :p

Answer (score 2):

As a new user, I can agree that it is quite frustrating not to be able to contribute, even if you're really here to help out. Like RegDwight said, it is to prevent new people from spamming. On Wikipedia, they do something similar since many people just create an account and never use it again. I think this also encourages users to gain more reputation points before they start posting dumb comments. Also users will trust your comments more if you have a bigger rep.