# Answer vs Comment

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what's the justification for the commenting reputation requirement?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66140/whats-the-justification-for-the-commenting-reputation-requirement)

Hi all, 
You need to have 50+ reputation points to be allowed to comment on other people posts, however you are allowed to post an answer with less points. In my opinion answers are more important than comments and sometimes when you still did not have 50 points you need to comment on someone's answer to add a little useful hint and then you will have to post it as a whole new answer which is not true.

What is the reason behind making comments harder than answers?

Comment: The rep limit on comments is to reduce spam.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion to give an answer to a question you need **knowledge**. Your answer is a statement of your known solution to given problem. This *statement* is yours only.

Commenting on the other hand is giving opinions on someone's else answer.

I consider this reputation requirement as a test for being "mature" enough on the site to culturally express your view on other people thoughts.

Comment: I had an issue with this too. Sometimes you just want to ask precisions to the original poster, but you can't comment and therefore, have to provide a non-answering answer to ask your questions.